# Как вычислить расхождение 2 многомерных массивов?

Tags: php

У меня есть 2 многомерных массива, мне нужно вычислить расхождение между ними, я пробовал их сравнить функцией array_diff но выводит ошибку, как я понял потому что array_diff принимает одномерный массив, мои массивы ниже

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => '1', 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => 'I', 'code' => '1', 'description' => 'Manufacturer 1', 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => '2019-02-19 20:02:45', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => NULL, 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => NULL, 'code' => NULL, 'description' => NULL, 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => NULL, ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => '3', 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => 'I', 'code' => '2', 'description' => 'Manufacturer 2', 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => NULL, ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => '1', 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => 'I', 'code' => '1', 'description' => 'Manufacturer 1', 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => '2019-02-19 20:02:45', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => NULL, 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => NULL, 'code' => NULL, 'description' => NULL, 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => NULL, ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => '3', 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => 'I', 'code' => '2', 'description' => 'Manufacturer 2', 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => NULL, ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => '1', 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => 'I', 'code' => '1', 'description' => 'Manufacturer 1', 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => '2019-02-19 20:02:45', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => NULL, 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => NULL, 'code' => NULL, 'description' => NULL, 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => NULL, ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => '3', 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => 'I', 'code' => '2', 'description' => 'Manufacturer 2', 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => NULL, ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => '1', 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => 'I', 'code' => '1', 'description' => 'Manufacturer 1', 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => '2019-02-19 20:02:45', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => NULL, 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => NULL, 'code' => NULL, 'description' => NULL, 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => NULL, ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'tablename' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'actionfield01' => '3', 'actionfield02' => NULL, 'action' => 'I', 'code' => '2', 'description' => 'Manufacturer 2', 'rtiprice' => NULL, 'colorcode' => NULL, 'colordescr' => NULL, 'size' => NULL, 'sizethesi' => NULL, 'category' => NULL, 'sezon' => NULL, 'sex' => NULL, 'age' => NULL, 'mnfid' => NULL, 'composition' => NULL, 'eshopdisable' => NULL, 'actionremarks' => NULL, 'iteremain' => NULL, 'addvalidate' => '1 ', 'actiondate' => NULL, ), )
```

Второй массив

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'ID' => 1, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '1', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => 'I', 'Code' => '1', 'Description' => 'Manufacturer 1', 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => '2019-02-19 20:02:44.647', 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 1 => array ( 'ID' => 2, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => NULL, 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => NULL, 'Code' => NULL, 'Description' => NULL, 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 2 => array ( 'ID' => 3, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '3', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => 'I', 'Code' => '2', 'Description' => 'Manufacturer 2', 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 3 => array ( 'ID' => 4, 'TABLENAME' => '5', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '6', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => '7', 'ACTION' => '8', 'Code' => NULL, 'Description' => NULL, 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'ID' => 1, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '1', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => 'I', 'Code' => '1', 'Description' => 'Manufacturer 1', 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => '2019-02-19 20:02:44.647', 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 1 => array ( 'ID' => 2, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => NULL, 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => NULL, 'Code' => NULL, 'Description' => NULL, 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 2 => array ( 'ID' => 3, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '3', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => 'I', 'Code' => '2', 'Description' => 'Manufacturer 2', 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 3 => array ( 'ID' => 4, 'TABLENAME' => '5', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '6', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => '7', 'ACTION' => '8', 'Code' => NULL, 'Description' => NULL, 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'ID' => 1, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '1', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => 'I', 'Code' => '1', 'Description' => 'Manufacturer 1', 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => '2019-02-19 20:02:44.647', 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 1 => array ( 'ID' => 2, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => NULL, 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => NULL, 'Code' => NULL, 'Description' => NULL, 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 2 => array ( 'ID' => 3, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '3', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => 'I', 'Code' => '2', 'Description' => 'Manufacturer 2', 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 3 => array ( 'ID' => 4, 'TABLENAME' => '5', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '6', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => '7', 'ACTION' => '8', 'Code' => NULL, 'Description' => NULL, 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 'ID' => 1, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '1', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => 'I', 'Code' => '1', 'Description' => 'Manufacturer 1', 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => '2019-02-19 20:02:44.647', 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 1 => array ( 'ID' => 2, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => NULL, 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => NULL, 'Code' => NULL, 'Description' => NULL, 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 2 => array ( 'ID' => 3, 'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '3', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 'ACTION' => 'I', 'Code' => '2', 'Description' => 'Manufacturer 2', 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), 3 => array ( 'ID' => 4, 'TABLENAME' => '5', 'ACTIONFIELD01' => '6', 'ACTIONFIELD02' => '7', 'ACTION' => '8', 'Code' => NULL, 'Description' => NULL, 'RtIPrice' => NULL, 'ColorCode' => NULL, 'ColorDescr' => NULL, 'Size' => NULL, 'SizeThesi' => NULL, 'Category' => NULL, 'Sezon' => NULL, 'Sex' => NULL, 'Age' => NULL, 'Mnfid' => NULL, 'Composition' => NULL, 'EshopDisable' => NULL, 'IteRemain' => NULL, 'ActionRemarks' => NULL, 'ActionDate' => NULL, 'AddValidate' => '1 ', ), )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот здесь решение вашей задачи

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/780780/PHP-Finding-differences-in-two-multidimensional-ar

```
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2)
{
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            if(!isset($array2[$key]))
            {
                $difference[$key] = $value;
            }
            elseif(!is_array($array2[$key]))
            {
                $difference[$key] = $value;
            }
            else
            {
                $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                if($new_diff != FALSE)
                {
                    $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
                }
            }
        }
        elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value)
        {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методом `array_udiff()`

`$diff = array_udiff( $old_array, $new_array, function ($a, $b) { return $a != $b; } );`

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но он не делает так как мне нужно, потому что, как я понимаю он не может сравнить многомерные массивы, для одномерного массива ваш ответ работает

Comment: @ПашаИванов добавьте ваши массивы в вопрос через `var_export`